# Use Remote Desktop on Win7 Logs out the current user

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I've done my homework and I everyone says that it's not possible to RDP a remote machine on win7 without logging of the current user, but I read somewhere that this happens `IF` you try to login to the remote machine with another user that is already logged in, is that true?

For example if on PC A user `xxx` is logged in, if I try to RDP to PC A with `xxx` user which is logged in already, he is not gonna kicked out? or is he?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you will resume your session as `xxx`. everything on your desktop from the interactive session will appear in your remote session and vice versa. you will not be logged out and then logged back in as the same user.

Comment: @FrankThomas but the `xxx` user will not see his desktop anymore and I will... .

Comment: yes, because you are xxx. are you trying to tell me you are using someone elses username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you define Kicked out.

The session itself will remain in tact, but the user behind the pc will no longer be able to use his computer.

An external RDP login will lock the computer in question if a user is logged in. The user will see a lock screen and can enter their password to resume working. The desktop is then prepared for the interactive remote session. If you login with the user currently logged in, you will resume that session. If not, you will start a new session, and the current logged in user's session will be paused.

If the user choses to start their session, they will disconnect your RDP session. In any case, the user will never be logged out, unless you issue a shutdown command while connected to the RDP and answer the question that you wish to reboot/shutdown despite other users being logged in.

So kicked out means: they cannot work on their computer at the same time as you RDP to it, but they can resume their session. If they do while you RDP to it, they will disconnect your session.