# Remote Desktop without affecting login user

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, active-directory

I would like to ask if it is possible to RDP computers in AD without affecting the current login user. I try RDP but upon submitting it automatically logs out the current user.

Is there a way I can make it like Team viewer where user can see what I am doing to their machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Remote Desktop on Win7 Logs out the current user](https://superuser.com/questions/819207/use-remote-desktop-on-win7-logs-out-the-current-user)

Comment: Hi Thanks. i'm looking for other way that currently logged in user can see the session while i'm remoting their machine.

Comment: Then you want Remote Assistance [QuickAssist, Win10] rather than RDP - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026516/windows-use-remote-assistance-to-let-someone-fix-your-pc